# web3.eth.net.isListening() throws Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" (web3@1.3.4)

Tags: web3js, quorum, error

I am using the latest web3 version 1.3.4.

When I connect to web3 and print web3 I get the following response.
[image]

But when I try to execute the command web3.eth.net.isListening().then(console.log). I get the following error.
[image]

Not only for this command but any command executed to fetch details from the Network shows the same error. Commands like web3.eth.getAccounts(), web3.eth.getCoinbase(), etc.

**Network Configuration**

```
Local Quorum Node : quorum-v2.4.0
Geth Version: v1.8.18
web3: v1.3.4
```

Can anyone please help me with a solution.